# ¿Cómo puedo evitar el error max_allowed_packet en las pruebas de integración?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

¡Hola!

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto .NET Web API Core 2.0 con Entity Framework y MySQL.

Tengo un problema con las pruebas de integración donde estoy usando una base de datos **InMemory**.

Mi *Startup.cs* es como la siguente:

```
namespace MiProyecto
{
    public class MiApplicationFactory<TStartup, TContext> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
        where TStartup : class
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        public TContext MiContext { get; set; }

        public CustomApplicationFactory(string relativePath, Action<TContext> seedEnsurer, IConfiguration configuration) :
          base()
        {
        }

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // ...

            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {

                // ...
                services.AddDbContext<TContext>(options =>
                {
                    options
                        .UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting")
                        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
                        .ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning));
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
                });
                // Valorando propriedad MiContext ...
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que recibo este error cuando hago la operación de seeding:

```
Message: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
---- MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

Un ejemplo de mio pruebas:

```
public class MiTests
{
    private readonly MiApplicationFactory appFactory;

    public MiTests()
    {
        appFactory = new MiApplicationFactory<MiStartup, MiEntityFrameworkContext>();
    }

    public void Get_should_return_data()
    {
        Entidad entidad = new Entidad();

        // Con muchas entidades --> 'max_allowed_packet' bytes error
        appFactory.MiContext.Set<MiEntidad>().AddRange(entidad);
    }
}
```

¿Como puedo resolver este problema?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El problema no es de C#, es de mysql y sus tiempos de conexion. tenes que configurar mysql para que acepte paquetes mas grandes.. Reformula la pregunta, con toda la info de mysql..

Comment: Hola gbianchi, muchas gracias por tu respuestas. Yo creo que el problema no es de MySQL porque estoy usando una base de datos "in-memory". ¿Estas seguro?

Comment: Dijiste que usabas mysql. Que tipo de version estas usando? el problema ese es tipico de mysql.

Comment: Perdoname, tal vez mi pregunta no es muy clara. Es verdad que estoy usando MySQL pero mi problema esta en la pruebas de integracion donde estoy usando una *InMemory* base de datos. Actualizo la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un detalle que debes configurar en tu motor de BD MySql.

Necesitas realizar ciertos cambios en tu archivo de configuración de MySql.

Cambia el archivo `my.cnf` ó `my.ini` ábrelo y dentro de la sección `mysqld` colocas lo siguiente (por defecto viene en `1M`):

```
max_allowed_packet=100M
```

o ejecutar estos comandos en la consola cliente de MySql en tiempo de ejecución:

```
set global net_buffer_length=1000000; 

set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```

(Usa un valor grande para que no te marque error.)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Saludos

Comment: ¡Hola! Muchas gracias for tu respuestas. Mi problema es que estoy haciendo pruebas de integracion con una base de datos *InMemory*. Yo no tengo una base da datos fisica donde puedo cambiar las configuraciones.